# Can I do a delay delivery in Thunderbird or Evolution

Tags: shell, email, sendmail, thunderbird, evolution

Now we have an option of `"Delay Delivery"` in `Outlook`.

Can we do something like that in `thunderbird/evolution` or any other linux client ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a ["Send Later"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/?src=cb-dl-recentlyadded) add-on for Thunderbird:

> True "Send Later" functionality to schedule the time for sending an email.

I'm afraid this functionality isn't possible with Evolution.

Using the command line, you can use a combination of the [`at`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at) command along with some mta such as [`ssmtp`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP), [`mailutils`](http://mailutils.org/) or [`postfix`](http://www.postfix.org/).

Example with mailutils:

```
echo "Test" | mail abc@def.com | at 7:30
```